# Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'System.runAs' at line 4 column 22

Tags: error, compile-error

Guys need some help in figuring out where I am going wrong. I am getting the above error at line 3.
Any help is appreciated.

```
@isTest
private class LabsContactLookupPopupController_Test {
    public static testMethod void testSearch() {
        System.runAs( System.runAs(TestDataUtil.createUser('TestUser'))){
            Id appOwnerId = TestDataUtil.appOwner_Creation(testContactLookup);
            String appOwnerId_String = String.valueOf(appOwnerId);
            LabsContactLookupPopupController controller = new LabsContactLookupPopupController();
            controller.setQuery(appOwnerId_String);
            controller.runQuery();
            List<Contact> resultContact = controller.getContacts();
            controller.setContactIdval(appOwnerId_String);
            system.assertequals(appOwnerId_String,controller.getContactIdval());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: removing my snippy comments because you formatted it properly right after.

You have `System.runAs( System.runAs(`. Remove one of them and it will compile, assuming your utility method is sound.